# How to cache partial crc32 checksums so I don't need to calculate it multiple times?

Tags: performance, caching, crc32

In some code that I wrote recently, I had this pattern:

```
from zlib import crc32

new_data = get_some_input()

crc32List['stream1'] = crc32(new_data, crc32List['stream1']) & 0xffffffffL
crc32List['stream2'] = crc32(new_data, crc32List['stream2']) & 0xffffffffL
...
crc32List['streamN'] = crc32(new_data, crc32List['streamN']) & 0xffffffffL
```

It seems to me, that there's a bit of redundant computation going on there and if I can find a function called `magic(x, y)` that does the following caching, I would be happy:

```
crc32List['cached'] = crc32(new_data, 0) & 0xffffffffL

crc32List['stream1'] = magic(crc32List['cached'], crc32List['stream1'])
crc32List['stream2'] = magic(crc32List['cached'], crc32List['stream2'])
...
crc32List['streamN'] = magic(crc32List['cached'], crc32List['streamN'])
```

'`magic(x, y)`' uses the cached 'x' crc32 value and returns the same result as '`crc32(new_data, y) & 0xffffffffL`'

Of course '`stream[0:N]`' begin with different values and end up with different values at any point in time, but the crc32 computation is almost always executed (90%+) for all N and always with '`new_data`'

Answer (score 1):

You did not provide a hint for what language this is with a tag, and I am not familiar with a version of a `crc32()` function that has arguments as shown.  In any case, what I think you're looking for is the `crc32_combine()` function of [zlib](http://zlib.net/).

The arguments to the actual `crc32()` function in zlib (in C) are `crc32(crc, buf, len)`, where `crc` is the starting CRC-32 value, `buf` is a pointer to the bytes to compute the CRC-32 of, and `len` is the number of bytes.  The function returns the updated CRC-32 value.

Given that:

```
crc32(crc32(0, seq1, len1), seq2, len2) == crc32_combine(crc32(0, seq1, len1), crc32(0, seq2, len2), len2)
```

Note that `crc32_combine()` needs to know the length of the second sequence as well as the two CRC-32 values in order to combine them.